# SharePoint 2010: MySites: Add custom tabs to My Profile

Tags: my-profile, my-site

I want to have custom tabs to My Profile of mysites (where you have overview, organization,etc). I was able to add these tabs by going into Site Settings->Look and Feel-> Navigation-> Add Heading, and point them to my newly created aspx page. However, I am not able to retain the user profile box if I can say (where you have the user info the tabs, etc). Any idea on how to retain it. I am trying to open up the `person.aspx` and mimic it but no luck yet. Any suggestions?

Edit:[image: UserProfileBox]

I have application pages linked to 'My Tab1' and 'My Tab2'. I want to have this (I would like to call it) 'user profile box' in my application page so that it look n behave similar to person.aspx, thought.aspx, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an overview and base project I put together on my blog to cover how the navigation is configured as well as the base content needed for a new page.
http://www.mikeoryszak.com/sharepoint/user-profiles-adding-a-custom-tab-and-page

Answer (score 1):

I dont have access to any dev box right now, but will try to guide you anyhow:

The web control you are refering to is placed inside the person.aspx page.

You could copy that control (and its tag prefix) from person.aspx to your custom page to make it look like person.aspx

Comment: Yeah, have been exploring the same, with no luck.

Comment: So whats not working? If you get errors paste log file

Answer (score 0):

The way I did was by entirelly copying the content of any of the pages whose behaviour you want to duplicate, and start from there! Just make sure you do keep all the things before the A tag with name="skipContactCard" in the PlaceHolderMain - that is what is generating the head part with  User profile properties.

"Simples" ! Drop me a message if you need more clarifications.